# Busboy sending response back before reading file length and file data? i am uploading single file

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, file-read, busboy, nodejs-server

```
module.exports.upload = function (req, res) {
  fileName = path.basename(req.query.fileName);
  var fileExtn = path.extname(req.query.fileName);
  console.log("fileName " + fileName);
  console.log("fileExtn " + fileExtn);

  var fileCheckResponse = FileCheck(req, res);  // FileCheck method containing Busboy code
  console.log("file check response =" + fileCheckResponse);
}

function FileCheck(req, res) {
var dataSize;
  var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      file.on("data", function (data) {
        dataSize=data.length;
      console.log("File [" + fieldname + "] got " + data.length + " bytes");
      console.log("the upload file data ===== " + data);

      })
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
      console.log('Upload complete');
      return dataSize;
    });
   return  req.pipe(busboy);
}`
```

here from upload method i am calling FileCheck function where Busboy code is present and i put debug and check in FileCheck function first it hits the line (  busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) ) then it doesn't goes inside it hits another line ( busboy.on('finish', function()) then response object goes back to upload method, i am expecting datalenght in fileCheckResponse but getting object which is not containing it, again on continue debug again it goes back to FileCheck function and this time it hits ( file.on("data", function (data)) and prints data on console as i have written but response doesn't comes back to upload method.

Here again my question and goal is to get datalength as response but now first time i am getting object as response and second time pointer doesn't come back to upload method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try using const or let instead of var

module.exports.upload = function (req, res) {

  fileName = path.basename(req.query.fileName);
  const fileExtn = path.extname(req.query.fileName)
  console.log("fileName " + fileName);
  console.log("fileExtn " + fileExtn);


  // try to make FileCheck function synchronous using promise or async await

  FileCheck(req, res)
    .then(fileSize => {
        console.log(fileSize, 'fileSize')
        // send whatever response you need
    })
}

function FileCheck(req, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let dataSize;
        let busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
        busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
            file.on('data', function (data) {
                dataSize = data.length;
                console.log("File [" + fieldname + "] got " + data.length + " bytes");
            })
        });
        busboy.on('finish', function() {
            console.log('Upload complete');
            resolve(dataSize)
        });
        req.pipe(busboy)
    })
}
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details? Why is a `const` preferred to `var` here? Why is using an asynchronous call important here?